# How to control which Fields are exported in ArcObjects? (via Field Mapping)

Tags: arcobjects, c#, geoprocessing, .net

In ArcMap 10.x, if you use the Export Data command on a layer that has hidden/disabled fields, those fields will not be present in the created feature class/table. My question is simple: how do you duplicate this functionality using ArcObjects and C#? The `IField` interface seems to have no property or method for defining this aspect of table data. Can it be done?

I am seeking to do this so I can extract a subset of fields from a table and keep it for later use (as opposed to having to deal with all the unnecessary data bloat present in many standardized data releases).

**UPDATE**: I am currently attempting to use the `IFieldInfo` option suggested in the comments below, but I find myself unable to perform the conversion from an `IFeatureClass` to an `IFeatureLayer` that seems necessary to access `ITableFields`. Am I missing something? I am doing this in a WinForms app, so there is no parent ArcMap instance open to obtain layer information from. I wish to only work with feature classes and tables, if possible.

**UPDATE 2**: It would seem that, because this winforms is detached from any instance of ArcMap, I cannot make use of `IFeatureLayer` to turn fields on and off before exporting. Does anyone know how to properly create a field map object in C#?

Comment: Regarding update 2, did you try creating a featurelayer, assigning the featureclass to IFeaturelayer.Featureclass, then set the visibility via ITableFields, then do the export ?

Comment: No, I haven't. Worth a shot, but for now, that method is no longer my preferred one.

Answer (score 4):

I've not written this all the way out but think I see a path. You can check the [IFieldInfo2.Visible](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/Visible_Property/00250000035p000000/). Once you have determined what fields are visible then you could do the export. For example you could create a QueryFilter and set its [SubFields](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/SubFields_Property/0025000006n4000000/) property and then use [IExportOperation](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//002900000029000000) passing in the QueryFilter.

Comment: IFieldInfo2.... Genius! I will try that now. It will take me about 30 years (or maybe a few hours) to implement this so I will get back to you tomorrow.

Comment: Ho hum, how would you get to the IFieldInfo2 interface when starting with a feature class? It seems to want an ITable.

Comment: All right, it seems that I can get `IFieldInfo` from `ITableFields`, but the latter interface only cooperates with feature layers, not feature classes. I know how to go from class to layer, but can you go backwards?

Comment: "Hidden" fields are a concept that applies only to feature layers and table views, not feature classes or standalone tables. I think you will need to revisit how you are determining which fields to keep since you aren't using layers.

Comment: Hm, I suppose a Merge Field Map will do the trick.