# exporting a featureclass to shapefile with selected fields only

Tags: vb.net, vb

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to control which Fields are exported in ArcObjects? (via Field Mapping)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/16691/how-to-control-which-fields-are-exported-in-arcobjects-via-field-mapping)

I want to export a featureclass to a shapefile.The only condition i want to impose is that shapefile should contain only selected field from featureclass.Somebody plz help out.

Comment: This question has been asked before. http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/16691/how-to-control-which-fields-are-exported-in-arcobjects-via-field-mapping

Answer (score 1):

1. Select feature class Properties
2. Go to Fields  Select require fields
3. Then Export Shape file.

Comment: Thanks RajGovind,But i need to do this programmatically....

Comment: I Dont aware the programming.